# OpenMP global private variable

Tags: c, function, task, openmp

I do have a question about my parallelized C-Code. Without changing the return type of `bar()` or adding parameters to `bar()`, I have no idea how to let `foo()` know about `*number` when it gets recursively called after `bar()` is executed.

Secondly I wanted to know if the comment after `bar()` is called explains the final clause of the task?
For the record, in this context, `r` is `maxIndex(A)`, `l` is `minIndex(A)`, `A` is an array of integers, and all 3 are function parameters of `foo()`.

```
int *number;
#pragma omp threadprivate(number)

void bar(...) 
{ 
    [...] 
    *number = i + 1; 
}

void foo(...)
{
    if(...)
    {
        bar(...);
        // no more tasks for arrays (< 100 elements)?
        #pragma omp task final(r - l <= 100)
            foo(*number - 1);
        #pragma omp task final(r - l <= 100)
            foo(*number + 1);
    }
}

int main(...)
{
    [...]
    #pragma omp parallel
        #pragma omp single
            foo(...);
    #pragma omp taskwait
    [...]
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this global variable, does it really have to be global?

Comment: It does not have to be global, it worked sequentially

Comment: I tried #pragma omp parallel private(number), instead of threadprivate but it does not work. Every foo() should have its own number, which have to be changed by bar() without return type or additional parameter.

Comment: Sorry to ask a question that might be obvious to you, but why a pointer? From what you show in your snippets, you only seem interested in the value that is pointed to, not by the pointer itself. Shouldn't the pointed value be `threadprivate` too (or `number` a value rather than a pointer)? And if you could come up with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), that would help us so much more to help you.

Comment: If it doesn't have to be global, can't you simply make it a parameter of `foo`? I can't say for sure, since I don't know what you're actually doing.

Comment: What you attempt to do is shooting yourself in the foot. Sure we can help you do that, but the result is bad code nonetheless. This is an X-Y problem. If you tell us what you really want to achieve, the we can tell you how to do so with a clean idiomatic solution.

Comment: It is a quicksort algorithm, my restrictions are to not change the return type or add parameters. the number dont have to be a pointer and saves the pivotIndex of the current recursion of foo().

Comment: Can you try to declare `number` an `int` and to modify your code accordingly? Your issue, although you didn't explain it unfortunately, might just be related to the pointed value to be shared between threads rather than private as it should be (or not)...

Comment: I modified to int number;

Comment: Also removed other * in front of number, but still not working.

Comment: main-function does A = malloc(n*sizeof(int)) and initalize the elements of A with rand() then calls foo(A, 0, n-1). Now in first foo(), bar(A, l, r) is called to determine number (= pivotIndex). Then foo() gets called twice recursively: foo(A, l, number-1) and foo(A, number+1, r)

Comment: it works when i use an additional parameter for bar() or change its return type to int, but i am not allowed to modify these because of fixed test units.

Comment: @koji0285 I've replied to your other question about `final` on your other SO question.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to pass a number from one function (`bar` or `find_pivot`) to its caller (`foo` or `quicksort`).

Using a global variable is a bad pattern for that. Change your tests that do not allow you to do that. Trying to work around that gives you unreadable, unmaintainable, and just painfully complicated code. In fact, it makes it so uselessly complicated that you can't even figure out how to write it yourself while the alternates are very simple.

Compare this:

```
int find_pivot(int *arr, int low, int high)
{
    return ...;
}

void quicksort(int *arr, int low, int high)
{
    ...
    int pivot_index = find_pivot(arr, low, high);
    quicksort(arr, low, pivot_index - 1);
    quicksort(arr, pivot_index + 1, high);
}
```

Or using a pointer (typically if you have several values, or a complex value, to return):

```
void find_pivot(int *arr, int low, int high, int *pivot_index)
{
    *pivot_index = ...;
}

void quicksort(int *arr, int low, int high)
{
    ...
    int pivot_index = -1;
    find_pivot(arr, low, high, &pivot_index);
    quicksort(arr, low, pivot_index - 1);
    quicksort(arr, pivot_index + 1, high);
}
```

With the following (wrong!), which is close to what you have written:

```
int pivot_index;

void find_pivot(int *arr, int low, int high)
{
    pivot_index = ...;
}

void quicksort(int *arr, int low, int high)
{
    ...
    find_pivot(arr, low, high);
    // What happens if two tasks call pivot_index simultaneously?
    // Which value will you get for quicksort? No way of knowing!
    quicksort(arr, low, pivot_index - 1);
    // pivot_index has changed value due to recursive quicksort() ! The next call is wrong!
    quicksort(arr, pivot_index + 1, high);
}
```

Not only is it less readable (e.g. when reading quicksort, where does pivot_index come from?), but it also needs to be fixed (don't use this, it's terrible!):

```
// can be set from several threads simultaneously
int pivot_index;
#pragma omp threadprivate(pivot_index)

void find_pivot(int *arr, int low, int high)
{
    pivot_index = ...;
}

void quicksort(int *arr, int low, int high)
{
    ...
    find_pivot(arr, low, high);
    // save value to protect from recursive calls
    int my_pivot_index = pivot_index;
    quicksort(arr, low, my_pivot_index - 1);
    quicksort(arr, my_pivot_index + 1, high);
}
```